# How to check if a widget got setWidgetHidden == true in SplitLayoutPanel?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Google provides `setWidgetHidden(Widget)` method for `SplitLayoutPanel` but i didn't see any method to check  if a widget got `setWidgetHidden == true` in `SplitLayoutPanel`.

Say i set `myWestWidget hidden == true` as following : `mySplitLayoutPanel.setWidgetHidden(myWestWidget, true);`

Then i tried this code `if (mySplitLayoutPanel.getWidgetSize(myWestWidget)==0) then //do something`, but it doesn't recognize if that west widget got hidden.

So, How to check if a widget got `setWidgetHidden == true` in `SplitLayoutPanel`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to subclass `SplitLayoutPanel` like this:

```java
SplitLayoutPanel slp = new SplitLayoutPanel() {
    public boolean isHidden(int i) {
        return ((DockLayoutPanel.LayoutData)getWidget(i).getLayoutData()).hidden;
    }
};
```

Comment: but, i created SplitLayoutPanel in UiBinder file. So u want me to create MySplitLayoutPanel & then change my UiBinder file?

Comment: is there other way that i don't need to change my UiBinder file?

Comment: also why Google "protected" so many useful methods like that?

Comment: when using custom widget xmlns:myWidgets='urn:import:my.client', i got an error
"The constructor MySplitLayoutPanel(Style.Unit) is undefined"